# Highest score data with more than one result - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to print student with highest score if there is more than one result?

```
var studentList = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){ Id =1, FullName = "May", CourseScore = 90},
            new Student(){ Id =2, FullName = "Joe", CourseScore = 65},
            new Student(){ Id =3, FullName = "Ann", CourseScore = 50}
        };

        var stud = studentList.OrderByDescending(c => c.CourseScore).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(stud.FullName);
```

The above query works but only if highest score has only one element. But if more than one student have the same highest score? For example, May and Ann also 90 CourseScore? How do show both May and Ann?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Group` items by `CourseScore` and select student names as following:

```
var stud = studentList.GroupBy(g => g.CourseScore)
                        .Select(i => new
                        {
                            CourseScore = i.Key,
                            StudentNames = String.Join(",", i.Select(s => s.FullName))
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.CourseScore).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(stud.StudentNames);
```

It will give you following result:

> May,Ann

Note: If there is only one student who has highest score, it also gives you one student name.

Comment: Did you tried with same highest scores? For example: `var studentList = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){ Id =1, FullName = "May", CourseScore = 90},
            new Student(){ Id =2, FullName = "Joe", CourseScore = 65},
            new Student(){ Id =3, FullName = "Ann", CourseScore = 90}
        };`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the following data

```
var studentList = new List<Student>() {
        new Student(){ Id =1, FullName = "May", CourseScore = 90},
        new Student(){ Id =2, FullName = "Joe", CourseScore = 65},
        new Student(){ Id =3, FullName = "Ann", CourseScore = 50},
        new Student(){ Id =4, FullName = "Jac", CourseScore = 90},
    };
```

You can try two ways

1) **process time is 15 milliseconds for my pc**

```
   var names = studentList.GroupBy(x => x.CourseScore).Select(y => new { CourseScore = y.Key, Names = string.Join(",", y.Select(x => x.FullName)) }).OrderByDescending(x => x.CourseScore).Select(x => x.Names).FirstOrDefault();
   Console.Write(names);
```

2) **process time is 1 milliseconds for my pc**

```
    var maxScore = studentList.Max(x => x.CourseScore);
    var names = studentList.Where(x => x.CourseScore == maxScore).Select(x => x.FullName);
    var joinedNames = string.Join(",", names);
    Console.WriteLine(joinedNames);
```

*They both prints: **"May,Jac"***